# Wordpress enqueued plugin script not loaded on frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

I have enqueued a stylesheet and a script from my wordrpress widget plugin class. I'm noticing that the css file are loaded but not the script. Is there a way to fix this? 
Here is the code I'm using:

```
public function initScripts()
  {
    wp_enqueue_style('instagram-widget', plugins_url( 'instagram-widget.min.css', __FILE__), array(), null);
    wp_enqueue_script('instagram-widget-js', plugins_url( 'instagram-widget.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery, swiper'), null);
  }
```

In the plugin construct I'm calling the method using the `add_action`:

```
public function __construct()
{
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'initscripts') );
}
```

Comment: did you loaded `swiper` script? is it loaded?

Comment: I've removed the dependency from the parameter and now all is working fine, thanks for the support

Comment: add upvote please :-D